# Vertical Form Inside Jumbotron

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something like this. http://www.lolnexus.com/

I am trying to build the search module but cannot get my form to vertically stack. How can I go about this better using bootstrap. I am trying to build the part where it says enter summoner name and under that the radio buttons but I cant seem to figure how to get that alignment at least the vertical alignment. Custom styling can come later.

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <form role="form" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <input type="search" size="100" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search for Summoner Name">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                    <label> NA</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" id="NA" value="NA" />
                    <label>EUW</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" id="EUW" value="EUW">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try changing column width of form-groups to 12 columns?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <form role="form" method="post">
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <input type="search" size="100" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search for Summoner Name">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                    <label> NA</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" id="NA" value="NA" />
                    <label>EUW</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="region" id="EUW" value="EUW">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tbh didnt even think that was the problem but that worked! Ty

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form class="form" role="form" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="search" class="form-control" size="100" id="mySearch" placeholder="Search for Summoner Name" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="region" id="NA" value="NA" />
                            NA
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                            <input type="radio" name="region" id="EUW" value="EUW">
                            EUW
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are lots of different classes you can use.  I recommend you study bootstrap better to understand it.  My example is for a form that spans the width of the container.  Below the search input are the radio buttons.  Below them is the search button.  Bootstrap, by default is a 12 column layout.  You were specifying 6 columns in width which placed the elements next to one another instead of vertically.  You can just add the form-inline class to the form-group divs to make those particular elements inline.  The form-control class makes the control span the width of its container.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you trying to do, but if you are trying to have `input` and the `button` in one row and the radio buttons underneath, just put both `form-groups` in a separate row as well and also add `col-md-offset-3` so it will be in the middle.

Comment: Trying to have the radio buttons below the search bar.

Comment: That was exactly my answer, but I guess it was easier just to copy and paste his answer.